# Can you somehow turn a String like "14232*12331-1231" into something Java can Calculate?

Tags: java, string, input, int, output

I'd like to know if you can somehow get something like

```
String test= "3445+100";
double x= test
```

so I can turn a typed in calculation into a result?

First time asking sorry if I waste your time :/

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Welcome to the community :). The basic answer would be "yes, you can", but you should show that you have tried to solve the Problem yourself. To get you started, though: look into the "split"-function for String to start off.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084984/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/

Comment: Try using .split("\\+");

Comment: You could use the Javascript enginge. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261329/math-string-with-no-spaces#23652514

Comment: What is the syntax of permitted expressions? Are parentesese permitted?

Answer (score 0):

```
String test= "3445+100";
String[] numberArray=test.split("\\+");
int a = Integer.parseInt(numberArray[0]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(numberArray[1]);

int solution=a+b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You split the String between the operators. Then you cast the Number-Strings to int and you can cast the Operators with a distinction of cases because you can have only +,*,- and /.